# How to verify OpenAM Agent password

Tags: openam

I have set up 15 Agents in OpenAM, and I have carefully noted down the passwords for each one in a safe place. Except, I made a mistake and for two passwords I do not know which Agents they are for.

Is there any way, through the OpenAM console/commandline-tools/etc to check a password against a particular agent?

I can't actually start the agents yet as we are not ready to activate them. Hence the need to do this check in another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just two password with two agents, I think you can use the http://YourOpenamAuthServ/openam/UI/Login For the login name use agent name and try the passwords. If it's the good one you will successfully log in.